# Why is it not recognizing that variable?

Tags: javascript

Why is my code not ducking working I've been debugging for an hour now ahhhh
I have to do it and I felt bad asking my instructor.
I dont know where my error is. It keeps giving me ones over the rrethi.onclick but i don't really know what to do please help me somebody.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #rrethi {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var rrethi = document.getElementById('rrethi');
    var shfaqKohen = document.getElementById('time');

    var kohaF = new Date().getTime();

    function shfaqeRrethin () {
      rrethi.style.display = 'block';
      rrethi.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 'px';
      rrethi.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 'px';
      kohaF = new Date().getTime();
    }

    var winner = 0;
    var array = [];

    rrethi.onClick = function () {
      rrethi.style.display = 'none';
      setTimeout(shfaqeRrethin, 3000);
      var kohaM = new Date().getTime();
      var koha = (kohaM - kohaF) / 1000;
    };

    shfaqKohen.innerHTML = koha + 's';
    winner = koha;
    array.push(winner);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Koha: <span id="time"></span></h2>
<div id="rrethi"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code snippet:

```css
#rrethi {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script>
    var rrethi = document.getElementById('rrethi');
    var shfaqKohen = document.getElementById("time");

    var kohaF = new Date().getTime();

    function shfaqeRrethin() {
      rrethi.style.display = "block";
      rrethi.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + "px";
      rrethi.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + "px";
      kohaF = new Date().getTime();
    }
    var winner = 0;
    var array = [];


    rrethi.onClick = function() {
      rrethi.style.display = "none";
      setTimeout(shfaqeRrethin, 3000);
      var kohaM = new Date().getTime();
      var koha = (kohaM - kohaF) / 1000;
    }

    shfaqKohen.innerHTML = koha + 's';
    winner = koha;
    array.push(winner);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Koha: <span id="time"></span></h2>
  <div id="rrethi"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Put `<script>` at the end of `<body>`. When the script runs, `#rrethi` does not exist yet.

Comment: `koha` is a local variable. `winner = koha;` is trying to access that local variable from global scope.

Comment: @terrymorse Although the effort to convert the code to a snippet is appreciated. You are removing quite an important aspect of the question. The original question had the `<script>` tag in the `<head>` and didn't use an doucment load callback. SO-snippets  execute the snippet JavaScript after the document is loaded.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I just now submitted an edit to restore the original code, and edited the snippet to reveal the execution order bug.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you can't access an element until it loads into the dom so calling `var rrethi = document.getElementById('rrethi');` in the Head will return undefined. It follows that when you try to call `rrethi.onclick` it throws an error.

Simply Wrapping the code in document.onload will make the js  wait till the dom loads before running, like so

```
 document.onload = function(){
        var rrethi = document.getElementById('rrethi');
        var shfaqKohen = document.getElementById("time");

        var kohaF = new Date().getTime();

        function shfaqeRrethin() {
            rrethi.style.display = "block";
            rrethi.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + "px";      
            rrethi.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + "px";  
            kohaF = new Date().getTime();               
        } 
        var winner = 0;
        var array = [];

        var koha = 0;
        rrethi.onclick = function() {
            rrethi.style.display = "none";
            setTimeout(shfaqeRrethin, 3000);
            var kohaM = new Date().getTime();
            koha = (kohaM - kohaF) / 1000;
        }

        shfaqKohen.innerHTML = koha + 's';
        winner = koha;
        array.push(winner);
      }
```

A few syntax/coding mistakes

1. moved koha out of the function scope so you have access to it outside the onclick function.
2. Changed onClick to occlick lowercase
3. The button starts out as display none so you can't click it to start
4. You need to update shfaqKohen.innerHTML within one of the onclicks for it to update

There are still Numerous mistakes but this should get you going

Comment: thank you, now its not giving me any errors but it still isnt doing what I want it to do, which is a cookie clicker type game with the red ball. Any help?

Comment: @Dielli I edited my answer with some code fixes as well as some suggestions